# Using jQuery Color Filler Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently in the process of trying to get the grasp of jQuery and have come across an error when testing out a demo with this plugin [HERE](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Change-Background-Color-Based-On-Image-Color-jQuery-fillcolor.html). Basically the error that I receive whenever testing on a .html file is ".fillColor is not a function". So I am wondering if the problem is that my src file has not been picked up correctly? I have tried re downloading the file and naming it differently but no luck!

Comment: Please post the javascript code where you call `fillColor`

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.fillcolor.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
  $('.js-fillcolor').fillColor();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="example js-fillcolor">
  <img width="200" height="200" src="https://unsplash.it/200/200/?image=10">
</div>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @J.Harris you should [edit] your question to include the code you just provided as it saves people having to read through comments in order to help you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can't find the file at the location you've told it.

To verify this, go into your address bar and change the part of the URL after the last slash (`/`) to "jquery.fillcolor.js" and it should take you to the location it's attempting to load. If it can't find the script there, you'll want to put it where it's looking. For example, if you're working in a single html file, it will need to be in the same directory as your html file, since your `src` doesn't have any slashes in it.